# Finding repeating digits at the end of a string of digits

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a list of 10 digit toll free phone numbers. I would like to identify those that contain at least 3 repeating digits in the last 4 digits of the number. For example:

```
8xxxxx5444
8xxxxx2220
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.  How about this one:

Put the phone numbers in column A

Then split out the last four chars:

```
Col B  =LEFT(RIGHT(A1,4),1)
Col c  =LEFT(RIGHT(A1,3),1)
Col d  =LEFT(RIGHT(A1,2),1)
Col e  =RIGHT(A1,1)
```

Then do a comparison in F:

```
=IF(OR(AND(B1=C1,C1=D1),AND(C1=D1,D1=E1)),"Yep")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but if your values (phone numbers) are in column A, you can add the following formula to column B (and copy it as appropriate).

```
=AND(MID(A1,8,1) = MID(A1,9,1), OR(MID(A1,7,1) = MID(A1,8,1), MID(A1,9,1) = MID(A1,10,1)))
```

It's kinda ugly, but it only uses 1 column.

Comment: When 8 and 9 don't match, but 7, 8, and 10 match I don't think this will work.

Comment: Jason, it will return FALSE as expected. if I am interpreting the question correctly, the 3 repeating digits must be sequential, so 8xxxxx7077 does not meet the criteria.

Comment: Ah, you may have understood the question better than I did.